# get the value from quote_item_option table (info_buyRequest) in GetCartDetails graphql Magento 2

Tags: magento2, cart, shopping-cart, graphql, pwa

How can we get info_buyrequest value using customer cart graphql magento2?

Any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by customer cart graphql but if you have the quote you can access the items options called `info_buyRequest` using the function `getBuyRequest()` on each item.

You can have look at this folder : `vendor/magento/module-quote-graph-ql/Model/Cart/BuyRequest`, maybe it contains the thing you need before coding new one.

Comment: an upvote and accepted answer would be nice then :-)